# Microservice messaging in go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, microservices, grpc

I am working on a project splitting services off of a monolithic codebase. Currently, the two services I am working on are a login/authentication service, a service providing a few REST API endpoints and a data retrieval service feeding the REST API. I need the services to exchange data with each other, in particular, data retrieval needs to send data to the REST API and REST API needs to exchange authentication requests/responses with the login service.

The technology of choice in go world seems to be protobufs and gRPC. I have been looking into using these, but it seems really inconvenient, so I wonder if I am just doing things wrong.

For example, my data retrieval gets records from an RDBMS and my REST API serves this data as JSON. Normally, I would define a "model" struct for each type of record in the database/API, use reflect annotations for both database and JSON in the struct definitions and used something like sqlx to scan query results into structs and encoding/json to serialize structs into JSON. But if I want to pass the data around using gRPC and protobufs this whole setup goes out of the window. Since protobuf generates its own struct types, I would have to manually implement conversion from SQL rows into protobufs and from protobufs into JSON for every single message type I define. Not that implementing conversions is hard, but it introduces more opportunities for bugs and code fragility and feels like reinventing the wheel.

And this seems like this should be a very common problem. Am I missing some obvious solution?

Comment: While protobuf & gRPC are certainly popular, so is bog-standard JSON REST. Have you done analysis to determine if using JSON REST throughout the whole system would be an appropriate solution for your use case? If it is, it certainly sounds like it might be simpler.

Comment: It seems that protobufs and gRPC might be a proverbial bandwagon. It makes sense for Google, with their huge distributed architecture and zillions of project teams to have a common communication protocol, but for small to medium projects it seems like more bother than a boon.

Comment: I am currently considering AMQP and a broker for my messaging and either JSON or MsgPack for my data format.

Comment: Protobuf and gRPC have advantages at scale because they are extremely efficient, both in terms of bandwidth and encode/decode compute. REST and JSON are much less efficient, but are more widely-known, widely-used, widely-supported, and generally easier to work with. There are a ton of options out there beyond just those two as well. Don't let what's popular/trending make your decisions for you, rather make an informed decision based on research & analysis (and prototyping if needed).